# 'exec' node is not showing in my node-red

Tags: exec, ibm-cloud, node-red

At left selection panel of node-red (node:0.12.x, node-red-bluemix:0.4.25), there is no 'exec' node in selections. Does anyone know why the 'exec' node is not showing? Should I install a separated node-red/node package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exec node is explicitly removed from the Bluemix instance as it doesn't really fit in the CloudFoundry app model to run things on the command line.

If you want to add it back, edit your `bluemix-settings.js` file to remove the `75-exec.js` entry from the `nodesExcludes` setting:  https://github.com/node-red/node-red-bluemix/blob/master/public/app/bluemix-settings.js#L36